# How solve the following PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the following PDE:$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0, \quad x\in\mathbb{R},\ t\geq x\\
u(x,x)=φ(x), \quad x\in\mathbb{R}\\
u_t(x,x)=0, \quad x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
$$
where $φ:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $φ\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried solve as duhamel's principle

Comment: As a first try, I would separate the variables writing $u(t,x) = a(t)b(x)$. If you replace this $u$ in the equation, after simple steps you may write a left hand side depending only on $t$, and the right hand side depending only on $x$. This means both sides must be constant. So you find two simpler equations $a''(t) = \alpha a(t)$ and $b''(x) = \alpha c^{-2} b(x)$, and the solutions of these are classified (they are linear ODEs). Watch out: I divided by $c$, so treat the case $c = 0$ separately.

Comment: as separation of variables?

Comment: Yes. You may assume the solution to be of the form $u(t,x) = a(t)b(x)$ and see what happens.

Comment: $u(t,x) = a(t)b(x)$, then $u_t(t,x) = a_t(t)b(x)$,  $u_t(x,x) = a_t(x)b(x)=0$, $a_t(x)=0$ and $a(t)=k$   for k constant ?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that $c^2≠1$?

Comment: No, it is not  guaranteed that $c^2≠1$

Comment: @CarlosAndresHenaoAcevedo Actually if a question is asked without showing efforts to solve it, it will probably get down votes and some users will also maliciously downvote answers to such a question. In this case, my answer is correct but it got down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

﻿$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$**Case 1:** $c^2 \neq 1$. Make substitution $(y, s) = (x - c^2 t, t - x)$, then$$
u_t = u_s - c^2 u_y, \quad u_{tt} = u_{ss} - 2c^2 u_{ys} + c^4 u_{yy}, \quad u_{xx} = u_{yy} - 2u_{ys} + u_{ss},
$$
and the equations become$$
\begin{cases}
(1 - c^2) u_{ss} - (c^2 - c^4) u_{yy} = 0, \quad y \in \mathbb{R},\ s > 0\\
u\bigr|_{s = 0} = φ\left( \dfrac{y}{1 - c^2} \right), \quad y \in \mathbb{R}\\
(u_s - c^2 u_y)\bigr|_{s = 0} = 0. \quad y \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases} \tag{1}
$$
Because $u\bigr|_{s = 0} = φ\left( \dfrac{y}{1 - c^2} \right)$, then$$
u_y\bigr|_{s = 0} = \frac{\d}{\d y} \left( φ\left( \frac{y}{1 - c^2} \right) \right) = \frac{1}{1 - c^2} φ'\left( \frac{y}{1 - c^2} \right),
$$
and (1) becomes$$
\begin{cases}
u_{ss} - c^2 u_{yy} = 0, \quad y \in \mathbb{R},\ s > 0\\
u\bigr|_{s = 0} = φ\left( \dfrac{y}{1 - c^2} \right), \quad y \in \mathbb{R}\\
u_s\bigr|_{s = 0} = \dfrac{c^2}{1 - c^2} φ'\left( \dfrac{y}{1 - c^2} \right). \quad y \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$
Thus\begin{align*}
u(y, s) &= \frac{1}{2} \left( φ\left( \frac{y + cs}{1 - c^2} \right) + φ\left( \frac{y - cs}{1 - c^2} \right) \right) + \frac{1}{2c} \int_{y - cs}^{y + cs} \dfrac{c^2}{1 - c^2} φ'\left( \dfrac{ξ}{1 - c^2} \right) \,\d ξ\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( φ\left( \frac{y + cs}{1 - c^2} \right) + φ\left( \frac{y - cs}{1 - c^2} \right) \right) + \frac{c}{2} \left( φ\left( \frac{y + cs}{1 - c^2} \right) - φ\left( \frac{y - cs}{1 - c^2} \right) \right)\\
&= \frac{1 + c}{2} φ\left( \frac{y + cs}{1 - c^2} \right) + \frac{1 - c}{2} φ\left( \frac{y - cs}{1 - c^2} \right),
\end{align*}
and$$
u(x, t) = \frac{1 + c}{2} φ\left( \frac{x + ct}{1 + c} \right) + \frac{1 - c}{2} φ\left( \frac{x - ct}{1 - c} \right).
$$

**Case 2:** $c^2 = 1$. Make substitution $(y, s) = (x, t - x)$, then$$
u_t = u_s, \quad u_{tt} = u_{ss}, \quad u_{xx} = u_{yy} - 2u_{ys} + u_{ss},
$$
and the equations become$$
\begin{cases}
2u_{ys} - u_{yy} = 0, \quad y \in \mathbb{R},\ s > 0\\
u\bigr|_{s = 0} = φ(y), \quad y \in \mathbb{R}\\
u_s\bigr|_{s = 0} = 0, \quad y \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases} \tag{3}
$$
which implies$$
\begin{cases}
2u_s - u_y = η(s), \quad y \in \mathbb{R},\ s > 0\\
u\bigr|_{s = 0} = φ(y), \quad y \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases} \tag{4}
$$
where $η(s)$ is a function to be determined. By the method of characteristics, the general solution to (4) is$$
u(y, s) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^s η(ξ) \,\d ξ + φ\left( y + \frac{s}{2} \right),
$$
and plugging it back to (3) yields$$
0 = u_s\bigr|_{s = 0} = \frac{1}{2} η(s) + \frac{1}{2} φ(y) = 0. \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}
$$
For the existence of solutions to the original equations, $φ$ must be a constant (namely $-η(0)$) and$$
u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{t - x} η(ξ) \,\d ξ - \frac{1}{2} η(0).
$$
It can be verified that $u(x, t)$ with the form above are indeed solutions.

Comment: thanks, in the case 1, why $\quad u_{xx} = u_{yy} - 2u_{ys} + u_{ss}$?
I have $\quad u_{xx} = 2u_y+4x^2u_{yy} - 4xu_{ys} + u_{ss}$

Comment: @CarlosAndresHenaoAcevedo Because $\partial_x=\partial_y-\partial_s$, then $\partial_{xx}=(\partial_y-\partial_s)^2=\partial_{yy}-2\partial_{ys}+\partial_{ss}$.

Comment: Sorry, I was taking the wrong change, you are right